# How to create a Triggered Send Definition using SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, wsproxy

I want to create a triggered send definition using SFMC SSJS.  This should be possible using either the TriggeredSend Platform object's Add method or via WSProxy. However, I can not get either to work.

NOTE: I am *NOT* trying to ***SEND*** a triggered send using a triggered send definition that has already been created. Rather, I want to ***CREATE*** the triggered send definition ***itself***.

**Using Platform Object** (as described in [SFMC Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_triggeredSendAdd.html))

```
var newTSD = {
   "Name" : "zzTSDDMPTemp",
   "CustomerKey" : "zzTSDDMPTemp",
   "FromName" : "Test From Name",
   "FromAddress" : "noreply@email.example.com",
   "EmailID" : 1449164,
   "SendClassificationID" : "Default Transactional"
};
var tsd = TriggeredSend.Add(newTSD);
```

Response is: "Error adding TSD."

**Using WSProxy** (following [SOAP Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/creating_a_triggered_send_definition.html) described here)

```
var newTSD2 = {
    Name: "zzTSDDMPTemp",
    CustomerKey:"zzTSDDMPTemp",
    SendClassification:{CustomerKey:"Default Transactional"},
    Email:{ID:1449164},
    SendSourceDataExtension:{CustomerKey:"TRV_ENT_ForwardDemo-TSD_TEST_DE"}
};

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var resp = prox.createItem("TriggeredSendDefinition", newTSD2);
```

Response is: Exception occurred during [CreateTriggeredSendDefinition] ErrorID: 1488072974

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust the official documentation, trust my documentation instead:

https://www.ssjsdocs.xyz/email-studio/triggeredsends/create.html

In a nutshell, you need to pass a valid **SenderProfile** and your Data Extension needs to be created with the **Triggered Send Data Extension Template**.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.